# Callback inside loop variable value resolved wrong

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

Supose I've:

```
var items = {
  '1': {
    id: 1
  },
  '2': {
    id: 2
  },
}

for (var item in itemns) {
  var item = items[item];

  $(object).on('signal', function () {
    doSomethingElse(item.id);
  });
}
```

Always `doSomethingElse` is called with `id = 2`, I know why it happens, but how can I avoid this in other words how can i workaround this ?

Comment: The question is what you want to achieve. You are binding two events (one with id=1 and an identical one with id=2). It is hard to see what the possible purpose could be. (Also, "var item = items[item];" is really, really ugly)

Comment: `object` would be two different objects, that when clicked delete the object with id 1, and 2 respectively.